# How to fix Angular highcharts ERROR TypeError xAxis?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have an Angular application and using this chart ([Source Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/sma-volume-by-price)). The chart is shown in UI but seeing the below error. Any recommendation how to fix or whats the issue?

```
main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'xAxis')
    at h.init (main.js:1:1434481)
    at h.gt.getArgs (main.js:1:1217544)
    at h.gt (main.js:1:1217391)
    at new h (main.js:1:1434394)
    at Object.w.stockChart (main.js:1:1435327)
    at e.updateOrCreateChart (main.js:1:636005)
    at e.wrappedUpdateOrCreateChart (main.js:1:635820)
    at e.ngOnChanges (main.js:1:635640)
    at e.dR (main.js:1:21372)
    at BR (main.js:1:25970)
```

Additional info:
The below code is directly taken from the above link with minimal data change.
The HTML part during compile does not show any error when building angular app.

```
<mat-tab label="Charts">
  <br>
  <div class="container" id="charts-content">
    <highcharts-chart
      class="col-sm"
      *ngIf="isHighcharts"
      [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
      [constructorType]="'stockChart'"
      [options]="chartsSectionStockChart"
      style="width: 100%; height: auto; display: block"
    >
    </highcharts-chart>
  </div>
</mat-tab>
```

```js
let unixtimeStmp;
let ohlc_list = [];
let vol_list = [];

this.backendServiceReq.getCompanyHistoricalData(this.ticker).subscribe(data => {
  this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData = data;

  if (this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData.length != 0) {
    let unixtimeStmp;
    let ohlc_list = [];
    let vol_list = [];
    let dataLength = data["c"].length;

    for (var x = 0; x < dataLength; x += 1) {

      unixtimeStmp = data["t"][x] * 1000;
      ohlc_list.push([unixtimeStmp, this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData["o"][x], this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData["h"][x], this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData["l"][x], this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData["c"][x]]);
      vol_list.push([unixtimeStmp, this.stockChartsSecHistoricalData["v"][x]]);
    }

    console.log("ohlc_list", ohlc_list);
    console.log("vol_list", vol_list);
    //https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/creating-custom-technical-indicators-financial-charts/
    //https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/sma-volume-by-price
    // create the chart
    //here
    this.chartsSectionStockChart = {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 2
      },

      title: {
        text: this.ticker.toUpperCase() + ' Historical'
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: 'With SMA and Volume by Price technical indicators'
      },

      yAxis: [{
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        labels: {
          align: 'right',
          x: -3
        },
        title: {
          text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: '60%',
        lineWidth: 2,
        resize: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }, {
        labels: {
          align: 'right',
          x: -3
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: '65%',
        height: '35%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2
      }],

      tooltip: {
        split: true
      },

      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataGrouping: {
            units: [['minute', [1]], ['month', [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]]
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        id: 'aapl',
        zIndex: 2,
        data: ohlc_list
      }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        id: 'volume',
        data: vol_list,
        yAxis: 1
      }, {
        type: 'vbp',
        linkedTo: 'aapl',
        params: {
          volumeSeriesID: 'volume'
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        zoneLines: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }, {
        type: 'sma',
        linkedTo: 'aapl',
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }

});
```

Passed data example:

```
vol_list:
0: (5) [1623628800000, 15.23, 15.3, 14.815, 14.87]
1: (5) [1623715200000, 14.91, 15.16, 14.76, 15]
2: (5) [1623801600000, 15.1, 15.29, 14.88, 15.02]
3: (5) [1623888000000, 15.3, 15.4, 14.58, 14.77]
4: (5) [1623974400000, 14.54, 14.765, 14.44, 14.52]
5: (5) [1624233600000, 14.63, 14.9, 14.55, 14.78]
6: (5) [1624320000000, 15.02, 15.11, 14.815, 14.91]
7: (5) [1624406400000, 15.14, 15.53, 15.03, 15.42]
8: (5) [1624492800000, 15.54, 15.55, 15.15, 15.26]
9: (5) [1624579200000, 15.24, 15.52, 15.18, 15.19]
10: (5) [1624838400000, 15.2, 15.21, 14.83, 14.96]
11: (5) [1624924800000, 15.05, 15.2, 14.875, 15.01]
12: (5) [1625011200000, 14.95, 15.11, 14.81, 14.86]
13: (5) [1625097600000, 14.91, 14.97, 14.84, 14.91]
....

ohlc_list:
0: (2) [1623628800000, 82666035]
1: (2) [1623715200000, 62612748]
2: (2) [1623801600000, 69112883]
3: (2) [1623888000000, 126653125]
4: (2) [1623974400000, 76319715]
5: (2) [1624233600000, 63384994]
6: (2) [1624320000000, 65545914]
7: (2) [1624406400000, 94985665]
8: (2) [1624492800000, 79859804]
9: (2) [1624579200000, 111760462]
10: (2) [1624838400000, 79477432]
11: (2) [1624924800000, 68208165]
12: (2) [1625011200000, 72213527]
13: (2) [1625097600000, 51112228]
14: (2) [1625184000000, 43824909]
15: (2) [1625529600000, 73990625]
16: (2) [1625616000000, 72992469]
17: (2) [1625702400000, 62706837]
18: (2) [1625788800000, 65981221]
19: (2) [1626048000000, 49205150]
20: (2) [1626134400000, 45360600]
21: (2) [1626220800000, 39056159]
22: (2) [1626307200000, 44952312]
23: (2) [1626393600000, 48065197]
24: (2) [1626652800000, 99949231]
...
```

[UI Chart Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgYxQ.png)

Comment: Hi @Ehsan, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? I've used your chart options, but there is no error. Live example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock-chart-1wuzay

Comment: Thank you for responding. in the next 1-2 days I will try to reproduce it.